# ZF2 and Codeception testing signup enters infinite loop after auth

Tags: php, zend-framework2, bdd, codeception

Problem:

I am using Codeception to test my Zend Framework 2 application. I want to test if user can sign in. Within my Auth controller this is the code:

```
$roleId = $this->identity()->admin()->getRole()->getRole_id();
$defaultRedirect =  AuthenticationRole::postLoginRedirect($roleId);
$url = $this->identity()->getReturnUrl($defaultRedirect);
// at this point, i am seeing in debugger that user has been authenticated, and proper url has been created (/admin/dashboard)
return $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
```

Next, i am doing this in my acceptance test:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Sign in');
$I->amOnPage('/admin');
$I->fillField('email', 'admin@example.com');
$I->fillField('password', '123456');

$I->click('Sign In');
```

When i run the test i am getting:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in .../vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Escaper/Escaper.php on line 135

As i could see while debugging is that use has been authorized, and when it comes to redirection, and redirected on /admin/dashboard, he is not recognized so he is redirected back to login form making that way an infinite loop.

What i tried so far:

- increased maximum nesting level to 1000 (already quite to much)- not helped.
- tried to redirect user with header('Location....)

Comment: Do you use PHPBrowser? Looks like state is lost (so you should set cookies manually in this case, or use WebDriver, it will manage cookies using real browser).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yes, i do use PhPBrowser, tried to set Cookies manual, did not help. Will google for WebDriver, thanks